# encoding utf-8 doesn't work with all German characters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, character-encoding

I read a geo pandas file like this:

```
file = gpd.read_file('./County.shp', encoding='utf-8')
file.head()
```

For some cases, the encoding works well. For example, without the encoding, it is `GÃ¶ttingen`but with the encoding, it is `Göttingen`.

However, it doesn't work for all cases. For example, `Gebietseinheit Mittelfranken ohne Großstadte` is read as `b'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried `ISO-8859-1` as encoding?

Comment: Try `latin` encoding

Comment: You have a difficult case (but not uncommon): data is stored with two different encodings. Probably somewhere a program used latin1 or cp1252, and so it read utf-8 as latin1/cp1252 and wrote it in latin1/cp1252. So you need to know your data, and try to solve it. If you have just German, decode in latin1, and replace the usually few cases of the character used in Germany. For other languages it may be more tricky (if they have consecutive accented characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\xdf` is `ß`; likewise, `\xe4` is `ä`:

```py
>>> '\xdf'
'ß'

>>> '\xe4'
'ä'
```

So there is nothing wrong with the encodings.

Really, it's because the file is read into a `bytes` string, which is what the `b` prefix means:

```py
>>> b'\xdf'
b'\xdf'

>>> b'\xdf'
b'\xe4'
```

So they're the same values, but Python is just displaying them differently.

Additionally:

```py
# With the b prefix:
>>> b'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'
b'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'

# Without the b prefix:
>>> 'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'
'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Großstädte'
```

If you want to print the string with the special characters looking normal, use `bytes.decode` to convert it to a `str`, **using the `latin` encoding**:

```py
>>> bytes_str = b'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'
>>> bytes_str
b'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Gro\xdfst\xe4dte'

>>> normal_str = bytes_str.decode('latin1')
>>> normal_str
'Gebietseinheit Kassel ohne Großstädte'
```